# Cannot connect to postgres server in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

I started a postgresql server in docker and exposed the 5432 port by `sudo docker run -it -p 5432:5432 9c421f1a239c bash` and start the postgres server manually inside the docker container, but cannot connect to it with command: `psql -h  172.17.0.63 -U venti`. `172.17.0.63` is a right IP, and venti is my pg username. But get error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "172.17.0.63" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

My pg_hba.conf looks like this:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust
local all all trust
```

Connecting to pg server inside container works successfully.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y gcc libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev libssl-dev libkrb5-dev comerr-dev

RUN apt-get install -y postgresql-common libpq-dev postgresql-9.1-postgis --fix-missing
RUN apt-get install -y postgresql postgresql-client

USER postgres

ENV PGDATA /etc/postgresql/9.1/main
ENV LOGDIR  /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.log

WORKDIR /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin
USER root
RUN apt-get install -y vim
USER postgres
RUN sed -e '90d' -i /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf
RUN sed -e '91d' -i /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf

RUN echo "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust" >> '/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf'
RUN echo "local all all trust" >> '/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf'

RUN ./pg_ctl start && sleep 8 && ./createdb pg && ./createdb bloodstone \
    && createuser -Upostgres -s venti \
    && createdb -Uventi -Oventi venti

# ENTRYPOINT ./pg_ctl start && bash -c "while true; do echo "" > /dev/null; sleep 1; done" 

VOLUME $PGDATA
EXPOSE 5432
```

Comment: you are missing the -p (port parameter before 5432:5432 ) in the command if it is not a typo

Comment: @ChandanNayak Sorry, it's just a typo...

Comment: Is your container still running after you exit from the running container ? Becasue you are not starting it with -d parameter

Comment: @ChandanNayak While debugging, I did not exit the container, so it's still running at least now.

Comment: please share your dockerfile

Comment: @ChandanNayak Seems I did not set the postgresql listen_addresses to public. So I add this line: ``RUN sed -e "s/[#]\?listen_addresses = .*/listen_addresses = '*'/g" -i '/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf'``. Seems solved the problem, still thanks!

Comment: answer your own question and close this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's merely a misconfiguration. I should have set pg to listen on public addresses or make a port mapping. I fixed this by editing pg config file with sed:

```
 RUN sed -e "s/[#]\?listen_addresses = .*/listen_addresses = '*'/g" -i '/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf'
```

Add this to a proper place in your Dockerfile, and you should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot postgres auth problems in general, look at the postgres log/stderr to see verbose reasons why it failed. (I see your problem is solved but if anyone runs into similar problems)

To find the postgres log location: "show log_destination;" if you have a working psql (eg locally on the postgres server box)

I see yours is set to "/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.log". You can connect to the container to see the log with "docker exec -it container_name bash".

Alternately, if a container runs postgres directly, "docker attach db_container_name" views postgres stderr messages.

Note that by default user postgres does not have a password and uses only ident auth.

Answer (score -1):

I also faced similar issue. Try running docker-compose up twice.

The reason is, that in my docker-compose.yml file the DB service was below the Web service in which it was trying to connect to DB which does not exists yet.

**

```
version: '2'  
services:
 nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: ng01
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /static:/static  <--- HERE
    depends_on:
      - web  
 web:
    build: .
    container_name: dg01
    command: bash -c "python /src/IMS/manage.py makemigrations && python /src/IMS/manage.py migrate && gunicorn IMS.wsgi -b
0.0.0.0:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - /static:/static 
    expose:
      - "8000"  
 db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: ps01**
```

Comment: That shouldn't be happening if you have `depends_on`